# "Look at" function returns a view matrix with wrong forward position? (Python implementation)

Tags: python, opengl, graphics

I am trying to understand the implementation of [gluLookAt](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml), follows one in Python.

```
import numpy as np

def lookAt(center, target, up):
    f = (target - center); f = f/np.linalg.norm(f)
    s = np.cross(f, up); s = s/np.linalg.norm(s)
    u = np.cross(s, f); u = u/np.linalg.norm(u)

    m = np.zeros((4, 4))
    m[0, :-1] = s
    m[1, :-1] = u
    m[2, :-1] = -f
    m[-1, -1] = 1.0

    return m

# test case 1
center = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
target = np.array([0.0, 0.0, -1.0])
up = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])

view = lookAt(center, target, up)
print('c: {}, t: {}, up: {}'.format(center, target, up))
print('view: \n', view)
print('forward: \n', -view[2, :-1])
print('\n')

# test case 2
center = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
target = np.array([-1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
up = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])

view = lookAt(center, target, up)
print('c: {}, t: {}, up: {}'.format(center, target, up))
print('view: \n', view)
print('forward: \n', -view[2, :-1])
```

And here's the output:

```
c: [0. 0. 0.], t: [ 0.  0. -1.], up: [0. 1. 0.]
view: 
 [[ 1. -0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
forward: 
 [-0. -0. -1.]


c: [0. 0. 0.], t: [-1.  0.  0.], up: [0. 1. 0.]
view: 
 [[ 0.  0. -1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1. -0. -0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
forward: 
 [ -1. -0.  0.]
```

My question is: why, when I specify a camera position of [0, 0, 0], pointing to [0, 0, -1], with an up [0, 1, 0], do I get a transformation matrix whose third column is [0, 0, 1, 0] instead of [0, 0, -1, 0]? According to the following picture I would expect the third column to represent the forward vector, which in the mentioned example should be [0, 0, -1, 0].

[image]

I was hoping I could conveniently extract the third column of the view matrix and use it as the forward vector to use in a `translate` transformation, assuming I would want to translate my camera in the forward direction for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you showed uses a right-handed coordinate system, where the view direction (in the camera's system) is along negative z. That's why there is

```
m[2, :-1] = -f
```

So, simply negate that entry to get the forward direction.

Keep in mind that look-at functions usually create a view matrix, which is the inverse of the camera's model matrix. The forward direction would then actually be the negated third row (not the third column). This is also what your code does, by the way.